# Returning Json from Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, anonymous-types

I am trying to return JSONified anonymous type from a WCF Service.

I have been successful in doing so, but I am searching for a better alternative..

```
// In IService
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ProcessExecutionFault))]
[Description("Return All Room Types")]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetAllRoomTypes", Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Stream GetAllRoomTypes();

// In Service Implementation

[LogBeforeAfter]
Stream GetAllRoomTypes()
{
   try
   {
       var allRoomTypes = Helper.GetAllRoomTypes();
       var stream = new MemoryStream();
       var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
       writer.Write(allRoomTypes);
       writer.Flush();
       stream.Position = 0;
       return stream;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       TableLogger.InsertExceptionMessage(ex);
       return null;
    }
}

// In Business Logic:

public string GetAllRoomTypes(){
    try
    {
       return CustomRetryPolicy.GetRetryPolicy().ExecuteAction(() =>
         {
          using (var context = new DatabaseEntity())
          {
             var retResult = from v in context.RoomMasters select new { Id = v.RoomTypeID, Type = v.RoomType };
             var retResult1 = retResult.ToJson();
             return retResult1;
           }
          }
         );
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Trace.Write(String.Format("Exception Occured, Message: {0}, Stack Trace :{1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
        return null;
      }
 }
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What about retuning [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675(v=vs.110).aspx), I did the same in [Nelibur](https://github.com/Nelibur/Nelibur). Here're [Service](https://github.com/Nelibur/Nelibur/wiki/How-to-create-REST-message-based-Servcie-on-pure-WCF) and [Client](https://github.com/Nelibur/Nelibur/wiki/How-to-create-REST-message-based-Client-on-pure-WCF)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `JavaScriptSerializer`

```
using (var context = new DatabaseEntity())
{
    var retResult = from v in context.RoomMasters select new { Id = v.RoomTypeID, Type = v.RoomType };
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var output = serializer.Serialize(retResult);    
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I have used an extension method ToJson that converts the object to json using Newtonsoft

Comment: Is there any better way to implement this functionality in WCF?

Comment: in WCF you can also use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) Class

Answer (score 0):

Use a class as your data contract instead of returning json directly. Then, in your method, just return a list or array of your data contract class. WCF will take care of serializing it to the configured format (JSON or XML).

```
[DataContract]
public class RommDto{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public RoomType Type {get; set;}
}
```

.....

```
[LogBeforeAfter]
RoomDto[] GetAllRoomTypes()
{
....
}
```

Comment: but it will require me to create such for each type.. any other better way?